# Counting Entities that all share the same first 3 characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am able to find the first 3 characters of a name using Substring and getting an output of what they are in a column by using the range between 1, 3. However I am unsure of getting the formal of:

```
Name   | Count
-------------
Jan    |  5
Feb    |  3
```

My current code is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3)
From Table
```

Which is giving me the necessary output, should I be using a HAVING Clause involving COUNT?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `COUNT(*)... GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3), COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3)
```